# Use ES6 proxy to trap Object.hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hasownproperty, es6-proxy

I want to use an ES6 proxy to trap the following common code:

```
for (let key in trapped) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) continue;
    let value = trapped[key];
    //various code
}
```

But after reviewing the [proxy documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), I'm not sure how to do it, mainly because the `has` trap trap is for the `in` operator, which does not seem to be used in the above code and there is no trap for the `hasOwnProperty` operation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to capture `hasOwnProperty()` calls.

Example:

```js
const p = new Proxy({}, {
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property) {
    if (property === 'a') {
      return {configurable: true, enumerable: true};
    }
  }
});

const hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

console.log(hasOwn.call(p, 'a'));
console.log(hasOwn.call(p, 'b'));
```

This is **specified** behavior, not a quirk of a particular implementation:

- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.hasownproperty) calls the abstract `[[HasOwnProperty]]` operation
- [`[[HasOwnProperty]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-hasownproperty) calls the abstract `[[GetOwnProperty]]` operation
- `[[GetOwnProperty]]` is what [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor` handles](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)

Answer (score 2):

I was actually going to answer my question myself, but I was too slow, and others answered it first (and added very useful information besides). Nevertheless, here is the answer I wanted to write, in case it might help someone somehow:

---

It appears that the `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap is fired when `hasOwnProperty` is called. So you can trap `hasOwnProperty` by doing the following:

```
getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, name) {
    return {
        value : target[name],
        //use a logical set of descriptors:
        enumerable : true,
        configurable : true,
        writable : true
    };
}
```

The other part is trapping `get` and `ownKeys` as well:

```
get(target, name) {
    return {}; //replace this with a relevant object
}

//These will be iterated over as part of the for loop
ownKeys() {
    return ["RelevantProperty1", "RelevantProperty2"];
}
```

All in all, since you have to return an array of properties when you trap `ownKeys`, using a proxy doesn't seem to make things much better in this use case. I think for the majority of situations, the following would work just as well and be less fragile:

```
let obj = {};
let keys = ["a" , "b"];
for (let key of keys) {
    obj[key] = {}; //relevant object
}
```

So using a proxy might be overkill.

Comment: It's usually better to prepare the answer before posting the question, so you can post them at once. Saves on these sort of situations happening. Still, useful nonetheless.

Comment: @vlaz that's a good point. I'll remember it in the future. Still, I'm glad Gothdo and others elaborated on how the mechanism works.