# Copy java script array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array `arr = [2,4];` I want to copy this array to another array `coppyArray = [2,4];` . Now I have 2 conditions to fulfill.

1. `coppyArray[i].value() == arr[i]`
2. `coppyArray.hasOwnProperty('value')` equal to `false`;

I was using `const coppyArray= [...arr];` but no luck. Can anybody please suggest how to achieve those condition using javascript or ES.

Comment: Just do try `coppyArray[i] == arr[i]`. It returns copied `value` at index `i`

Comment: where is `value` coming from?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. As @NinaScholz said, `value()`/`value` seems to come out of left field. Also, you've asked how to copy an array into another array, which your `const coppyArray = [...arr];` will do (it's one of several ways to do it, depending on what actual end result you want).

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have 2 conditions to fulfill.
>
> 1. `coppyArray[i].value() == arr[i]`
> 2. `coppyArray.hasOwnProperty('value') equal to false;`

The second condition is easy: arrays don't have a property called `value`, so we don't have to do anything special to satisfy that condition.

The only way to satisfy the first condition is to create an array of objects, for instance with `map`:

```js
const arr = [2,4];
const copy = arr.map(n => ({value() { return n; }}));
console.log(copy[0].value() == arr[0]);    // true
console.log(copy.hasOwnProperty("value")); // false
```

---

If you've shared the second condition incorrectly and it was *supposed* to be that `coppyArray[i].hasOwnProperty('value')` is false, then we can use the prototype chain for the `value` function:

```js
class Entry {
    constructor(n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
    value() {
        return this.n;
    }
}
const arr = [2,4];
const copy = arr.map(n => new Entry(n));
console.log(copy[0].value() == arr[0]);       // true
console.log(copy[0].hasOwnProperty("value")); // false
```

or without a constructor function:

```js
const proto = {
    value() {
        return this.n;
    }
};
const arr = [2,4];
const copy = arr.map(n => {
    const entry = Object.create(proto);
    entry.n = n;
    return entry;
});
console.log(copy[0].value() == arr[0]);       // true
console.log(copy[0].hasOwnProperty("value")); // false
```

Comment: *(Okay, enough procrastinating, back to what I'm* supposed *to be doing now...)*

Answer (score 1):

Solution using JS Proxies:

```js
const get = (target, prop, reciever) => prop === 'hasOwnProperty' ? () => false : ({ value: () => target[prop] });
const arr = [2,4];
const copyArr = arr => new Proxy(arr, {get});
const copyOfArr = copyArr(arr);

console.log(copyOfArr[0].value() == arr[0]) // true
console.log(copyOfArr[1].value() == arr[1]) // true
console.log(copyOfArr[1].value() == arr[0]) // false
console.log(copyOfArr[0].value() == arr[1]) // false
console.log(copyOfArr.hasOwnProperty("value")) // false
```

If you need to override the `hasOwnProperty` in a better way then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451694/use-es6-proxy-to-trap-object-hasownproperty/40451845#40451845).